# Count the comma in each line and show the line numbers in a text file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm using the following script to get the comma counts.

```
Get-Content .\myFile | 
% { ($_ | Select-String `, -all).matches | measure | select count } | 
group -Property count
```

It returns,

```
Count Name   Group
----- ----   -----
  131 85     {@{Count=85}, @{Count=85}, @{Count=85}, @{Count=85}...}
    3 86     {@{Count=86}, @{Count=86}, @{Count=86}}
```

Can I show the line number in the `Group` column instead of `@{Count=86}, ...`?

The files will have a lot of lines and majority of the lines have the same comma. I want to group them so the output lines will be smaller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use something like this?

```
$s = @"
this,is,a
test,,
with,
multiple, commas, to, count,
"@

#convert to string-array(like you normally have with multiline strings)
$s = $s -split "`n"

$s | Select-String `, -AllMatches | Select-Object LineNumber, @{n="Count"; e={$_.Matches.Count}} | Group-Object Count

Count Name                      Group                                                                                                        
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                        
    2 2                         {@{LineNumber=1; Count=2}, @{LineNumber=2; Count=2}}                                                         
    1 1                         {@{LineNumber=3; Count=1}}                                                                                   
    1 4                         {@{LineNumber=4; Count=4}}
```

If you don't want the "count" property multiple times in the group, you need custom objects. Like this:

```
$s | Select-String `, -AllMatches | Select-Object LineNumber, @{n="Count"; e={$_.Matches.Count}} | Group-Object Count | % {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        "Count" = $_.Name
        "LineNumbers" = ($_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber) 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Count    LineNumbers 
-----    ----------- 
2         {1, 2}   
1         3   
4         4
```

Comment: The files will have a lot of lines and majority of the lines have the same comma. I want to group them so the output lines will be smaller.